# configureStore argument is not a valid reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks, redux-toolkit

I have made sure both of my reducers work, and all imports are valid

```
const store = configureStore({ 
  reducer: {
    drinks: drinksReducer,
    selectedDrinks: selectedDrinksReducer
  } 
});
```

but this gives me the error: "Store does not have a valid reducer. Make sure the argument passed to combineReducers is an object whose values are reducers."

When i only pass in one reducer:

```
const store = configureStore({ reducer: drinksReducer });
```

the code works, but as soon as i make it an object with reducers as values, the code gives me an error. How do i fix this?

Comment: Does one of your reducers reference `store`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it suggests, the param object has reducers as property, for multiple reducers, combineReducers can help to group them together and return another reducer. [combineReducers](https://redux.js.org/api/combinereducers)

```
const store = configureStore(combineReducers({ 
    drinks: drinksReducer,
    selectedDrinks: selectedDrinksReducer
}));
```